# How to limit the size of file when picking the files in Android using file picker using Intent?

Tags: android

I want to pick files using Intent file picker but with a condition that the file size should not be greater than 5 MB. Can anyone please help me in this regard on how to limit the file size?

```
Intent intent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
} else {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
    intent.setType("image/*");
}

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: there is no such way

Comment: you need to show alertdialog/any dialog to user once he selects/pick the image in `onActivityResult()` method by getting the uri of image from intent result. Using `Fileproviders` to get file path and cross check that file size using `file.length()` against your size.

Comment: You need to check file size in `onActivityResult()`.